# Return change (pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that returns the number of pennies, nickels, dimes and quarters for a certain change (given the cost and the amount of money given).

I wrote the following code, but the output is always 1 penny. What should I change?

```
penny = 0.01
nickel = 0.05
dime = 0.10
quarter = 0.25

def return_change(cost, amount):
    
    number_of_pennies = 0
    number_of_nickels = 0
    number_of_dimes = 0
    number_of_quarters = 0
    change = amount - cost
    
    while change > 0:
        
        if change > quarter:
            change -= quarter
            number_of_pennies += 1
          
        if dime < change < quarter:
            change -= dime
            number_of_nickels += 1

        if nickel < change < dime:
            change -= nickel
            number_of_dimes += 1

        if penny < change < nickel:
            change -= penny
            number_of_pennies += 1

                    
                
        break
        
print(f'Given that the change is {amount-cost}$, we will give it in:\n{number_of_pennies} Pennies\n{number_of_nickels} Nickels\n{number_of_dimes} Dimes\n{number_of_quarters} Quarters')
```

Comment: 1. You increment `number_of_pennies` in `if change > quarter`. 2. You always break out after 1 loop of while. In such cases, a debugger helps massively.

Comment: Also some of your `<` and `>` should be `<=` and `>=`. For instance, you can give a quarter as change as long as `change >= quarter`.

Comment: What does `cost` and `amount` represent?

Comment: @AnnZen Evidently `cost` is the amount of money required for the payment, and `amount` is the amount of money paid.

Comment: Seems that the obvious change would be to add a docstring to `return_change` :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `mod`, also known as the remainder operator (%) and floor division.

Convert everything to cents first to avoid handling decimal numbers.

For example, if I need to give $1.41 => 141 cents.

1. Quarters (25)

   141 // 25 = 5 (Give 5 quarters)

   141 % 25 = 16 (16 cents left over)
2. Dimes (10)

   16 // 10 = 4 (Give 4 dimes)

   16 % 10 = 6 (6 cents left over)

And et cetera for the rest of the values.

Comment: You can combine the calculations with [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. It's pretty short and simple. The differences here vs your way are:

- we include a lot more money values (so we don't return ex: 384 quarters)
- we loop over all of the possibilities til there is no more change to process
- we handle the imprecision of float
- we concoct our final message in a loop
- we only print currencies that are returned at least one time

**code:**

```
import math

cur_values = [10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 100, 25, 10, 5, 1] #amounts are in pennies
cur_names  = ['$100', '$50', '$20', '$10', '$5', '$1', '25¢', '10¢', '5¢', '1¢']

def return_change(cost, paid):
    exc = []
    chg = round((paid-cost)*100)
    cur = cur_values[::]

    while chg > 0:
        c = cur.pop(0)
        exc.append(math.floor(chg / c))
        chg -= int(exc[-1]*c)

    teller = f"Total Cost: ${format(cost, '.2f')}\nPaid: ${format(paid, '.2f')}\nYour change is:\n"
    for n, c in zip(exc, cur_names):
        if n > 0:
            teller = f'{teller}\t{n} {c}\n'

    return teller


print(return_change(3.85, 100.00))


# Total Cost: $3.85
# Paid: $100.00
# Your change is:
#         1 $50
#         2 $20
#         1 $5
#         1 $1
#         1 10¢
#         1 5¢
```

Answer (score 0):

Four errors I can spot:

`number_of_pennies += 1` should be incrementing quarters not pennies on the first run.

No need for a break in the while loop

The print should be in the function

Also, I'd probably use integers and count in pennies or use a decimal class so you don't have weird rounding issues.

It may look like a lot's wrong, but this is a good start - keep going with your Python!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation that uses a `while` loop for each coin, and minimizing the required amount of coins:

```
penny = 0.01
nickel = 0.05
dime = 0.10
quarter = 0.25

def return_change(cost, amount):
    number_of_pennies = 0
    number_of_nickels = 0
    number_of_dimes = 0
    number_of_quarters = 0
    change = amount - cost
    while change-quarter > -0.01:
        number_of_quarters += 1
        change -= quarter
    while change-dime > -0.01:
        number_of_dimes += 1
        change -= dime
    while change-nickel > -0.01:
        number_of_nickels += 1
        change -= nickel
    while change-penny > -0.01:
        number_of_pennies += 1
        change -= penny
    print(f'Given that the change is {round(amount-cost,2)}$, we will give it in:')
    print(f'{number_of_pennies} Pennies')
    print(f'{number_of_nickels} Nickels')
    print(f'{number_of_dimes} Dimes')
    print(f'{number_of_quarters} Quarters')

return_change(23.54, 34.69)
```

Output:

```
Given that the change is 11.15$, we will give it in:
0 Pennies
1 Nickels
1 Dimes
44 Quarters
```

The `> -0.01` you see should ideally be `>= 0`, but when parsing, the numbers break up a little.

Answer (score 0):

I would not print within function but return some datastructure. This makes function more general and reusable. I would solve displaying results separately using datastructure returned by function.

One possibility to solve change part is to use divmod mentioned by @Chris Charley and dictionaries (must be 3.6 < Python as relies on insertion ordering of dictionaries; function is not defensive i.e. does not handle amount 0 as it's unclear what should be returned):

```
def change(amount, units={25: 'quarter', 10: 'dime', 5: 'nickel', 1: 'penny'}):
    quantities = dict()
    for value, name in units.items():
        quantities[name], amount = divmod(amount, value)
        if not amount:
            break

    return quantities

# change(141) -> {'quarter': 5, 'dime': 1, 'nickel': 1, 'penny': 1}
# change(100) -> {'quarter': 4}
```